# Using shell script to parse all ip:port values from a line

Tags: shell

I need to parse all ip:port values in a line from the single line string shown below using shell script. I tried a lot by using `awk`, `cut`, `sed`... but was not successful. Please help me. This (long) line is stored in a variable, not in a file.

```
14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO conf.Configuration: dfsdb.properties not found 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.6.133:54310 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.9.65:54310 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.9.66:54310
```

Update: I think I got some better code...

```
echo "<STRING>"| grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{4,5}"
```

Comment: Looks like you've solved your own problem; I suggest you put the solution in an answer yourself and then accept it (after 48 hours - see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: you can probably simplify the regex to `\([0-9]{1,3}\.\){3}[0-9}{1,3}:[0-9}{4,5}` though it could be cryptic at first glance.

Comment: Thanks mklement and alvits...

Comment: alvits, please check ur script. I think you miss-typed.
That script will be : 
echo $str|grep -oE "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{4,5}"

Comment: Is that what you see from `echo $variable` or from `echo "$variable"`?  The output looks like it should be 4 lines, rather than a single line. OTOH, your `grep` command line uses `"<STRING>"` rather than `<STRING>`, so...

Comment: I m sorry for missed to place quotation marks.
My input has single line.
so script will be:
echo "$str"|grep -oE "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{4,5}"

Answer (score 1):

there might not be straight and easy ans because of your requirements,
but this can work for you,

```
var="14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO conf.Configuration: dfsdb.properties not found 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.6.133:54310 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.9.65:54310 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.9.66:54310"
```

for separating your output,

```
echo $var | cut -d ">" -f2,3,4,5
```

--- assuming you have only 5 values. if more apply loop or try split command to take into an array and iterate over it

```
output : 172.20.6.133:54310 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.9.65:54310 14/03/25 11:53:50 INFO util.DFSDBUtil: NAMENODEIP--->172.20.9.66:54310
```

ip:port pair

```
 echo $var | cut -d ">" -f2  |cut -d " " -f1
```

output

```
172.20.6.133:54310
```

for each field apply loop and get the desired ip:port and if possible to simplify your trouble customize input string so that you can split it and feed it easily to cut command.

Comment: Thanks Nachiket...
Please check below code.I think i got some better code...
echo "<STRING>"| grep -oE "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}:[0-9]{4,5}"